# How do I apply an arbitrarily-phased single qubit gate in pytket?

Tags: quantum-gate, pytket

This is the specific gate I want to implement using pytket:
[corresponding Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate)

[image: Wikipedia entry of Phase shift gate]

I tried:

```
from pytket import Circuit
circ = Circuit(1)
circ.U1(angle)
```

But I got the following error:

**pytket._tket.circuit.Circuit' object has no attribute 'U1'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you did figure out that pytket supports the U1(angle) gate which is another name for the P(angle) gate.

To add this gate you need the OpType enum. This is sometimes the case with less common gates.
[pytket OpType enum](https://cqcl.github.io/tket/pytket/api/optype.html)

```
from pytket import Circuit, OpType
from sympy import Symbol
from pytket.utils import circuit_to_symbolic_unitary

angle = Symbol('a')
circ = Circuit(1)
circ.add_gate(OpType.U1, angle, [0])

circuit_to_symbolic_unitary(circ)
```

[image: screen shot of code]

Comment: Thank you!! Exactly what I was looking for!